# How to hide shortcut text of toolbar on taskbar windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, toolbar

Currrently in Windows 7 taskbar, we can add toolbar to have extra spaces for shortcuts by

`Right click on taskbar` -> `Toolbars` -> `New...`

But the icon/shortcut will have the text below it.

How can we remove that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlock the taskbar, right-click inside the toolbar and untick "show text" and untick "show title"
[image]